# Linux bash - Loop though files and summary up a value in that files

Tags: bash, loops, summarize

how would you do that

1. Loop through files based on a pattern
2. Extract a value from within that files (value is always there and a number)
3. Summarize all these values
4. echo the sum out

Many thanks in advance and greetings

Answer (score 0):

To less info to be more exact. So I leave a template only:

```
let sum=0
for f in __PATTERN__
do
    value=__extract__from "$f"  # any functionality ...
    let sum+=value
done
printf "summary: %u\n" $sum
```

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help] - instead of answering, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.